# Low resolution back ground appears blurry

Tags: game-maker-studio-2

I am trying to use a premade stage from an old game as my background. Its resolution is 4864 x 184. I've tried every setting in graphics options and any other related settings. I think its related to the texture page size but I can't find any information on how to change the size.

Thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

But it is not the best solution in the case. I would recommend to spilt the background into smaller pieces (two 2048*184 and one 768*184) because otherwise it may not work on some old hardware.

Comment: Is changing texture page size exclusive to payed versions because I have tried changing that before and I only have 2048 X 2048 as an option.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know because never tried free version. Anyway I don't recommend using values higher than 2048*2048